# Find $x$ for $[809x] = [214]$ in $\mathbb Z_n$ where $n= 5124$ s.t $0 \le x < 5124$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics

The following is dealing with equal classes under congruence modulo $n$.
I was told to use my answer for $[809x] = [1]$ in $\mathbb Z_n$ where $n=5124$ s.t $0 \le x < 5124$, so basically it's inverse. I found that to be $[5105].$ Not really sure how that's suppose to help me.. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$[809x]=1$ is equivalent to $809x+5105 k_1=1$, for some $k_1 \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Since you find that $x=5105$, we have $809 * 5105 + 5124 k_1=1$.

Then $809 * 5105 *214 + 5124 k_2=214$, for some $k_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Then you just have to find the remainder of $5105*214$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$, or just consider the equivalence class $[5105*214]$.

Note that this is a bit rough, and you may have to show uniqueness.